# How do I get my images to responsively resize with shuffle.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, image-resizing, shuffle

I am using shuffle.js on my [homepage](http://ajsdesign.net/) and I am trying to get my images to responsively  resize like in this demo the developer posted [here](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/images/).

Right now I am just using media queries as a workaround, but the results are far from ideal.

Note: the grid is already responsive, what I would like to see is for the images themselves to resize as well.

Comment: The link homepage leads to nowhere.. Please check

Comment: The homepage is http://ajsdesign.net/

Answer (score 1):

You must use a CSS Grid to have a nice responsive combined with Shuttle.

Note the classes **.span3** and **.m-span3** on   element

The example of your link is using Bootstrap v2.3.2.
You can use the Twitter Bootstrap 3 which has better semantic as well, or any other grid system.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

If you use Bootstrap 3, add the class **xs-col-12** and **col-4** like so:

```
<div id="grid" class="shuffle">
    <div onclick="window.location.href = 'IEMA.html'" class="xs-col-12 col-4 item Aston shuffle-item filtered ">
        <div id="overlay">ASTON</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="window.location.href = 'Aston.html'" class="xs-col-12 col-4  item Aston shuffle-item filtered">
        <div id="overlay">IEMA</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to include Bootstrap, you can add http://996grid.com/ with same way, using class **.grid_4** shoud be fine.

Update

> I can make some adjusts for your page have a better grid with shuffle changing for this style for your items when lower than 690px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 690px)
    .item {   
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 223px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify my question: I'm not looking to resize the grid, that already works. I want the images themselves to resize.

Comment: Check my update, I added some background and sizes values for your .item

Comment: I tried your last suggestion, but it does not keep the images' aspect ratio, It just resizes the width. Is there a way to resize both the height and width while keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Please, follow humble.rumble comment and post an example of your  shuffle code here and I'll fix it for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> To clarify my question: I'm not looking to resize the grid, that already works.

You have already a responsive class attached to the image's container,

> I want the images themselves to resize.

then you only need to add `max-width:100%` to the `img` element.

In my case :

```
  <figure class="xs-col-12 col-4 picture-item" data-title="The Magic Box">
    <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
     <div class="aspect__inner">
      <img style="max-width:100%" src="/the-magic-box.png" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>The Magic Box</figcaption>
  </figure>
```